# Table operation after export and import of data does not give me the same result

Tags: matrix, export, import, list-manipulation

If I create a table of this kind:

```
(m1 = Table[{RandomInteger[], RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {3}]}, {i, 1, 
 5}]) // MatrixForm
```

which looks like

[image]

I know how to pick the first column of the second column:

```
m1[[All, 2, 1]] // MatrixForm
```

which looks like

[image]

But if I first export and then again import the matrix m1

```
Export["data.dat", m1, "Data"]
m2 = Import["data.dat", "Data"]
```

I do not get the same result as previously

```
m2[[All, 2, 1]] // MatrixForm
```

which looks like

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: If you just want to save/retrive the data use "m" or "mx" format, eq `Export["data.m",m1]` these are "native" mathematica formats and will safely preserve whatever expression you export. If you really want to use the "Data" format for some reason that will take a bit of work to read it back in (clarify if that's what you need.. )

Comment: @george2079 Seems I somehow misinterpreted the docs ("Data": give data in a generic form (list, string, etc.)), I thought this was the one I had to add. I did not want to export as "Data" format, so actually your comment contains the solution to my problem. Could you please put it here as answer? I will mark it then.

Comment: Ok, anyway, +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you export a `Table`, then the array cannot be arbitrarily nested. What you should do is to export your data (which is not a matrix!) in a different format. Try:

```
Export["data.dat", m1, "Package"]
Import["data.dat", "Package"][[All, 2, 1]] // MatrixForm
```

or

```
Export["data.dat", m1, "MX"]
Import["data.dat", "MX"][[All, 2, 1]] // MatrixForm
```

and read the documentation of these formats.

Comment: Thank you, this works, too +1, but the solution suggested by george2079 is sufficient for me (it's shorter).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are exporting as text, and when you import back into Mathematica, it will see extra commas. To get the desired default, either export as csv

```
Export["data.csv", m1]
```

or WDF

```
Export["data.wdx", m1, "WDX"]
```

Comment: 'Export["data.wdf", m1, "WDF"]' gives in the case of my matrix m1
'Export::infer: Cannot infer format of file data.wdf. >>'

Comment: My bad, I meant WDX. It's Wolfram's proprietary file format. Try 'Export["data.wdx", m1, "WDX"]'. Works for me.

Comment: Yes, it works, not the 'Export["data.csv", m1]', however.

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem is. At a glance, it looks correct, but Mathematica actually exported the inner list as a string (without added commas, so it's not too bad). You can still use this format if you do just one extra process after import:
`m2 = Import["data.csv", "Data"];`
`m2[[1, 2]] // FullForm`
`m2[[All, 2]] = Map[ToExpression, m2[[All, 2]]]`
`m1 == m2`
`m2[[1, 2]] // FullForm`

Comment: Ok, thank you for the effort!